# Contraction of prepositions and definite articles in German

Tags: grammar

I could not find a table of the contractions of prepositions and definite articles in German, so I made one by my own:
[image]

Is this an exhausting table of all the contraction there are?

Comment: Just to point this out, there are quite a few mistakes in your table: it should be `ins`, `übers`, ... Note that there's also _übern_ for _über den_.

Comment: Du hast recht, ich werde es sofort zu korrigieren

Comment: @Hendrik Vog, Do other preposition besides *über* form a contraction with *den*?

Comment: It's probably regional usage, but I hear sometimes "aufm", too.

Comment: Das klingt interessant!

Comment: I think now you could apply colors to cells with colloquial contractions to make it even better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of those are colloquial and are avoided in formal speech. Personally I'd classify "vorm", "hinterm", "unterm", and "überm" as colloquial.

There exist similar colloquial contractions for other prepositions, e.g., "nebens", "außerm", or "wegem" (in colloquial speech "wegen" takes the dative case, not the genitive).

By looking at the table, I realized that these contractions are pretty regular:

- They are created by appending the last letter of the article to the preposition.
- n + m is replaced by m.
- Where a contraction would in phonologically unwieldy constructs (e.g. n + r), none exists.
- Contractions only exist for grammatically correct combinations (since "bei" requires the dative case, there cannot be any "bei das" or "beis").

Answer (score 2):

Ich benutze diese:

[image]

Die tabelle finden Sie [HIER](http://www.mein-deutschbuch.de/lernen.php?menu_id=14#verschmelzung)